# Using PowerShell, open Excel com object in safe mode or any way that prevents macros running

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a bunch of .xlsb files I need to pull data out of and migrate to a FileMaker database. The issue I'm running into is some of the files have a macro that runs immediately when the file is opened even through the com object due to the way the macro works.

This is how I'm currently opening Excel files. Does anyone know a way to open an Excel com object in safe mode? Any other way which would prevent the macros from running would also work.

```
$objExcel = new-object -ComObject excel.application
```

Comment: In my testing the Auto_Open macro will not fire when opened using $objExcel.Workbooks.Open(). Just how are your macros running? What is their trigger?

Comment: It's running using Workbook_Open().

Comment: Zach, unfortunately I got the same results as you. The Workbook_Open() macro RUNS. I can't figure a way out of it directly. You could try playing with the Excel Trust Center options to disable all macros and see if that works long enough for you to copy your data out and then re-enable your previous settings. Do this by opening a blank workbook in Excel and then File->Options->Trust Center.

Comment: I appreciate the effort. I did set the trust center settings. There is a reg key that can be set as well which I haven't tried. I've also tried $objExcel.AutomationSecurity = 'msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable' which doesn't seem to work correctly either.

Comment: Ok it appears I was wrong. I thought setting objExcel.AutomationSecurity = 'msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable'  wasn't doing anything, but indeed it was. That seems to have resolved my issue.

Comment: Zach, glad you got it resolved. I'll tuck that little piece of information away for future use.